# Can downvoting questions encourage their improvement?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

There is this problem with some questions - some important details are missing. People post comments suggesting that the OP add these details (e.g. additional pieces of code, or results of specific debugging actions), but OP doesn't add these details.

(side note: here are my conjectured reasons for *why* he doesn't do it:

- Too lazy
- Doesn't understand that he can *edit* the question
- Misjudging the constructive comments as offensive
- Hopes that some exceptionally smart people can answer his question without additional clarifications

)

Sometimes, when I see this with no reaction from OP, and his post has no votes, I downvote the question just to nudge him (and upvote a comment that requests the additonal info).

Does this have any chance to help? Are there any experimental data that show whether this behavior is constructive?

Also - would a comment like this be constructive?

> -1 (or *downvoted*) until you add details on X and Y, requested by user Z

I understand that mentioning voting in comments is frowned upon (or maybe banned - not sure) - but would this be an exception? Why? Why not?

---

I am effectively "holding their question hostage until a certain action is taken" - as noted by Kevin B. I don't see it as a threat - I already did the negative action - it's more like a promise: "I'll take my negative action back when/if you do a certain action". My idea is that it's easy to ignore (or just genuinely miss) comments, but a big bad "-1" near your content on the Internet asks for action! (maybe)

Comment: I don't see how mentioning the fact that a vote occurred for that reason is helpful. It's more of a threat rather than a nudge in the right direction. It looks like you're in a way holding their question hostage until a certain action is taken. Better to leave the comment without the opening portion, simply ask for what is needed.

Comment: You need to close vote, not just down vote.

Comment: My point is they shouldn't be combined, the vote should be because the question is unclear, and the comment should be to help the user make it more clear. I wouldn't downvote *because* they aren't improving the question, i would downvote because it is unclear *right now*, and if that changes in the future, i may reverse the downvote, but i likely won't simply because it's unlikely i'll come back unless they mention me in a comment after doing so.

Comment: You could add to your list:  'Cannot supply the info/debug details you ask for because the posted code was copy/pasted from some site or another student and the poster has no clue how to go about obtaining such details', (and would almost certainly not bother anyway - involves effort).

Comment: Can downvotes result in improvement, yes.  I've seen it happen, but it's certainly not super common.  Most people are unwilling/unable to improve their question no matter what you do, so downvotes also have the added utility of signaling to others that a question is bad, and not just incentivizing the author to fix them.

Comment: I remember it happening a few times too.  Too few.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would hope a down vote helps.

However voting (either up or down) is not (only) meant for the OP. It should be used as a quality signal to other visitors of the post.

The down vote tooltip states for that reason:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or  not useful

Leaving comments is only productive if you're willing to invest the time to really interact with the OP to help them improve the post. If it is only to pester them, anonymous voting should do.

There is voting data available in SEDE but only the date of the vote is recorded, not the time. Us mortals can't query for data to proof the hypothesis that down voting helps.

Comment: I know a downvote certainly motivates me to improve. Not that I've received one in a while, but probably because I was righteously downvoted early on.